Assertj not able to read a null field using 'extracting'
I am trying to extract a null field and assert it is null. However, assertJ reads the field as Boolean false instead of null.
the field i am trying to extract is marked below. As you can see it is null

however, when i extract it, it is read as Boolean false as seen below

I am not sure if this is an assertj bug or i am doing something wrong

Could you please provide a reproducible example? Feel also free to raise an issue at https://github.com/assertj/assertj/issues/new, we'd be happy to look into it.

i found the cause of the error which was that the ScriptChoice class implemented an interface with default interface method isOtherwise() returning Boolean. hence the 'extracting' method used this interface method instead of accessing the field directly. by using the method, it returned boolean false instead of the expected null
